# How to handle "Domain of sender address ee@e.com does not exist" error exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, sendmail

I want to make this message `"Domain of sender address ee@e.com does not exist"` shows to client instead of debug error. How can I make it?

In default, following debug error message is show.

```
Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 250 but got code "553", with message "553 5.1.8 <ee@e.com>... Domain of sender address ee@e.com does not exist "
```

I want to make this error message shows to client to tell them their email address is not exists, please try others. How to handle this error message?

Comment: reads like it was translated by google

Comment: does this happen synchronously? Or does the sending happen in the background. Also what is giving you the error? your local mail server? or a far end one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receipent e-mail server will run a series of tests to determine the legitimacy of the sender e-mail server and the sender e-mail addresses your server is trying to send.

The usual tests include reverse DNS match, SPF record match, clean from DNSBL, and of course the domain must exist.

The receipent e-mail server can -- and probably will -- refuse your e-mails if one or more of those tests fail.

Answer (score 2):

That error occurs, because [`e.com`](http://e.com) doesn't exist - [in fact very few single-letter second-level domains exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain).

To correct that error you are getting, use a valid email address, or at least use a domainthat exists. If it for an example or placeholder, you can use the ICANN [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) domain.